# Issue with two direction scrollview and tableview in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I am trying to create the following result in XML with android

[image]

Its a table with row for each user followed by their team picks for each week.

The table also needs to be able to scroll both vertically and horizontally as it will not fit all in one screen.

Here is the XML i have done so far:

```
<ScrollView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/activity_scrollView"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
 android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
 android:fillViewport="true">

    <HorizontalScrollView
     android:id="@+id/activity_horizontalView"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">

         <RelativeLayout
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          tools:context=".SurvivorAllPicksActivity">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
             android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />

         </RelativeLayout>

     </HorizontalScrollView>

 </ScrollView>
```

And the XML which I inflate the view is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<TableLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView android:padding="5dip" />

        <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="5dip"
         android:text="Pool Players"
         android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
         android:id="@+id/week"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="5dip"
         android:text=""
         android:textAlignment="center"
         android:textSize="10sp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView android:padding="5dip" />

        <!-- Player Username -->
        <TextView
         android:id="@+id/username"
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:padding="5dip"
         android:text=""
         android:textSize="10sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

                 <FrameLayout
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                     <ImageView
                      android:id="@+id/teamLogo"
                      android:layout_width="40dp"
                      android:layout_height="40dp" />

                     <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/teamInit"
                      android:layout_width="40dp"
                      android:layout_height="12dp"
                      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                      android:background="@color/text_gray_666666"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:text=""
                      android:textAllCaps="true"
                      android:textColor="@color/white"
                      android:textSize="8dp"
                      android:textStyle="bold" />

                 </FrameLayout>

             </RelativeLayout>

         </TableRow>

     </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the issue I am seeing is that when the program runs nothing is displayed and I am thinking my XML has issues... can anyone provide any insight to what I did wrong with my code in order to achieve whats in the image?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have one too many scrollable items having 2 scrollview and 1 recyclerview (which also scrolls) and it looks like your recyclerview contains a tablelayout of just 2 rows, which means these rows won't align correct with the other tablelayouts of the other recyclerview items.

As you probably want the "Players" column and the "Weeks" row to be sticky headers, this is a fair amount of work to do yourself.

I suggest that you use one of 2 libraries:-

https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView

Which is efficient but has a few issues with synchronising the columns.

or

https://github.com/Zardozz/FixedHeaderTableLayout

Which is less efficient but has no synchronisation issues and has the added benefit of pinch zooming.

Comment: so what i want to do can not be done via XML?

Comment: Given that you are trying to use a RecyclerView which requires code to populate it you are already not using XML alone and unless you have a static number of players and weeks then it is impossible just to use XML, you will always need code to create the right number of rows and columns.

Comment: Agreed, and I know that I would require code, but it would reference the XML by using the `itemView.findViewById(R.id.week)` as an example and then user `onBindViewHolder(SurvivorAllPicksViewHolder holder, int position)` to reference how the code would modify the actual view, and build it dynamically based on the number of players and number of weeks. etc... My question/issue is that nothing appears in the view even tho i have code in the `onbindViewHolder` and it maybe due to my XML file, possibly the combination of linearlayouts and scrollviews etc...